# Positive Lookbehind in Postgres 9.5 using regexp_replace

Tags: regex, postgresql, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

I have values like this: 1ST, 2ND, FIRST, and I want to remove the 'ST' and 'ND' ONLY if what comes before is a digit.

I am running postgres 9.5 and I have a **positive lookbehind** working in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e415b/7) but it only works on 9.6

```
SELECT ex,
regexp_replace(ex, '(?<=[0-9]+)(TH|ST|ND|RD)', '', 'gi') as test 
FROM t1
```

Is there any other way to do this besides using a CASE statement like this:

```
SELECT ex,
(CASE WHEN ex ~ '\d(TH|ST|ND|RD)' THEN regexp_replace (ex, 'TH|ST|ND|RD', '','gi') ELSE ex end) as test_case
FROM t1
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does my answer below help? Please provide feedback if you need any adjustments

Comment: This is great thank you! I'm new to both backreferences and word boundaries. So you basically use a positive lookahead **(?:TH|ST|ND|RD)** to match and capture and then replace the entire thing with the backreference to the digit ([0-9]).  Thanks again!

Comment: `(?:TH|ST|ND|RD)` is a [*non-capturing group*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471) that does not create a special memory buffer and that you cannot backreference to. Then, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match and capture the digit and replace with a backreference to the value. Also, I suggest adding a word boundary after the ordinal numeral suffixes to make sure we are matching them at the end of the word.

```
SELECT regexp_replace(ex, '([0-9])(?:TH|ST|ND|RD)\y', '\1', 'gi') as test_case FROM t1
```

See the [updated SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e5605/1).

```
CREATE TABLE t1
    (ex varchar)
;

INSERT INTO t1
    (ex)
VALUES
    ('1ST'),
    ('2ND'),
    ('3RD'),
    ('4TH'),
    ('FIRST'),
    ('FOURTH')
 ;

SELECT regexp_replace(ex, '([0-9])(?:TH|ST|ND|RD)\y', '\1', 'gi') as test_case FROM t1
```

[image]